# How to refer to a custom field in a node template?

Tags: theming, nodes, 8, entities

For the basic page content type I added a custom boolean field called field_login_required.

In my node template node--page.html.twig I have

```
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
    {% if content.field_login_required %}
        {% if user == 0 %}
        <p class="must-login">You must be logged in to view this page <a href="/user">Please click here to login</a></p>
        {% else %}
            <p>{{ content.body }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        <p>{{ content.body }}</p>
    {% endif %}
```

However content.field_login_required is null no matter whether the checkbox is checked or not. To test what was available I used

```
{{ dump(content|keys) }}
```

However the result of this is

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'body' (length=4)
```

field_login_required is omitted. Is there anyway to refer to a custom field in a node template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurred because

```
{{ content.field_login_required }}
```

was used. Node should be used in place of content. The proper code is

```
{{ node.field_login_required.value }}
```

Comment: that's not correct because the field object will always exist. if you want to check if the checkbox is checked or not, use node.custom_field.value

Comment: You are correct I'm updating the answer to reflect this